# A Question with using scapy.sniff for get the 'Ethernet Frame' in pcap files

Tags: scapy, pcap

Aim: Get the arrival time from the pcap files 
Language: python3.7
Tools: Scapy.sniff

Above all ,i want get the arrival time data,in the ***.pcap ,when i use wireshark ,i saw the data in the Ethernet Frame,but when i use 
 #Scapy.sniff(offline='***.pcap') ,i just get the Ether,TCP,IP and others ,so how can i get that data?
Thanx alot!

```py
>>from scapy.all  import *
>>a = sniff(offline = '***.pcap')
>>a[0]

[out]:
<Ether  dst=*:*:*:*:*:* src=*:*:*:*:*:* type=** |<IP  version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x20 len=52 id=14144 flags=DF frag=0 ttl=109 proto=tcp chksum=0x5e3b src=*.*.*.* dst=*.*.*.* |<TCP  sport=gcsp dport=http seq=1619409885 ack=1905830025 dataofs=8 reserved=0 flags=A window=65535 chksum=0xfdb5 urgptr=0 options=[('NOP', None), ('NOP', None), ('SAck', (1905831477, 1905831485))] |>>>
[ ]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packet time from the pcap is available in the `time` member:

```
print(a[0].time)
```

It's kept as a floating point value (the standard python "timestamp" format). To get it in a form more easily understandable, you may want to use the datetime module:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(a[0].time)
>>> print(dt)
2018-11-12 03:03:00.259780
```

The scapy documentation isn't great. It can be very instructive to use the interactive help facility. For example, in the interpreter:

```
$ python
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> a = sniff(offline='mypcap.pcap')
>>> help(a[0])
```

This will show you all the methods and attributes of the object represented by `a[0]`. In your case, that is an instance of `class Ether(scapy.packet.Packet)`.

Comment: Thanks very very much! And i will try to help(a[0])  then.  Thanks again!!!